# Microsoft Outlook AppleScript error

Tags: applescript

got this script for use with outlook

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    set sentFolder to folder "Sent Items" of default account
    set current view to sentFolder
end tell
```

yet i keep getting an error in script editor

`A property can’t go after this identifier.`

any clue?

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: in the 4th line `set current view to sentFolder`

Comment: You may want `set selected folder to sentFolder`.

Comment: amazing @MarcWilson, thank you so much! I have the same error in another code chuck:


```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set selectedMessages to selected objects
    repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages
        set flagged status of theMessage to flagged clear
    end repeat
end tell

```


again its in the 4th line `set flagged status of theMessage to flagged clear`, any clue?

Comment: Try `set theMessage to not flagged`.