# AppleScript to toggle Outlook followup or clear it based on state of message

Tags: applescript

I have this script

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages
        if flagged status of theMessage is true then
            set flagged status of theMessage to false
        else
            set flagged status of theMessage to true
            set due date of theMessage to missing value -- remove any existing due date
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

that should toggle a follow-up with no date and clear followup on outlook on the mac

im getting this error in script builder:

`Expected “then”, etc. but found property.`

and it shoes the line:

`if flagged status of theMessage is true then`

any clue whats wrong here?

Comment: How is this different than your question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470938/microsoft-outlook-applescript-error?noredirect=1#comment700712_470938 ?

Comment: thx @MarcWilson as aways you rock. I couldn't get the last question solved after your kind answer (im suck ad coding.. ) do I need to change the `if flagged status of theMessage is true then` line and change `true` to `flagged`? that didn't seem to work. really appreciate your help

Comment: You always need to specify what line you are getting the error message on.